# Google calendar with a service worker

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

Trying to create events for a calendar on my personal gmail account from visitors from my website. However I can't seem to get it to work.

Currently I am getting

```
  ...
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  request: {
    responseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2023-03-03T17%3A37%3A25.280Z&maxResults=10&singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime'
  }
}
No upcoming events found.
```

This is strange because I created some calendar entries under the account where the service account is registered.

I read that service workers cannot operate outside of google workspace, however the errors were different to my own making me think that they had changed this.

To summize I am asking if it is possible to create calendar events from my server, to a personal calendar, without needing to get workspace?

I have created and listed calenders from this service worker. using the `calendarId: "primary"`. These events are being created and listed, so they exist. However they aren't on my personal account. And likewise my personal account, where the service worker is registered under, does not show the events in my personal calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create google calendar events for consumer accounts using a service account. The reason behind that is that you will need to perform DWD for the service account and then impersonate the user, but `gmail.com` is not a domain you own, so it will fail.

There is however, a way for you to create event on your consumer account without a service account. It requires you to follow the flow of [OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server).

The key part of the above flow is to obtain an access token with a refresh token. Store the refresh token somewhere safe. Make the api calls to the google calendar api with the access token, if expired, used the refresh token to get a new access token and so on.

Comment: Lifesaver thanks. Do you know why, and possibly where, the events are being created?

Comment: Yes, the events should be created in the calendar id you specify. If you are using the keyword `primary`, then it will be created on whatever primary calendar of the authenticated account. Most of the calendar ids are simply the email address of the user, so you can use the email address instead of the keyword `primary`.

Comment: In that case why can't I use the email address of the user that the service account is registered under? Or use the calendar of the service account and add that to a calendar app or whatever?

Comment: Well, you can create events on the calendar of the service account, however, there is no UI for it to be displayed because service accounts are different, So the only way to manage those event would be through api. But to answer your question, you can create the events on the service account calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Web server workflow works just fine, however if you want to use a service worker workflow, you must share the calendar with the service worker, and use the email address of the owner of the account as a `calendarId` instead of `primary`